# FireStore Batched writes on different Collections

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there an alternative way to perform set of writes on multiple documents belongs to various ***Collections***?

Sort of like **Batched Writes** on multiple ***Documents*** as in official docs.

[Transactions and batched writes on FireStore Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

For an instance;

```
WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

// Set the value of 'NYC' in 'cities' collection

DocumentReference nycRef = db.collection("cities").document("NYC");
batch.set(nycRef, map1);


// Set the value of 'ABC' in 'SomeOtherCollection' collection

DocumentReference otherRef = db.collection("SomeOtherCollection").document("ABC");
batch.set(otherRef,map2));
```

Is that *possible* to perform Batched writes on different collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Batch operations can work across collections. From the [documentation on batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes):

> ```
> // Get a new write batch
> WriteBatch batch = db.batch();
>
> // Set the value of 'NYC'
> DocumentReference nycRef = db.collection("cities").document("NYC");
> batch.set(nycRef, new City());
>
> // Update the population of 'SF'
> DocumentReference sfRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
> batch.update(sfRef, "population", 1000000L);
>
> // Delete the city 'LA'
> DocumentReference laRef = db.collection("cities").document("LA");
> batch.delete(laRef);
>
> // Commit the batch
> batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
>     @Override
>     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
>         // ...
>     }
> });
> ```

Since you pass in the document to write to `batch.set()`, you can also pass in a document from a different collection to each call.

Comment: Just wanted to know if it is possible just like I have shown in my example.

Comment: It would be nice if the documentation had an example of this since it does not explicitly spell it out.

Comment: @ChristopherFitzner yes. I found this post looking for exactly that. Usually, missing things like this in the FB docs means it's a hard no.